# How to remove master node from a Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

Using version 2.4.0 here.
I can decommission a non-master node by executing:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{
    "transient" : {
        "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "192.168.1.10"
        }
    }'
```

after the re-allocation, the node removed from the cluster automatically.

However, when i came to removing the **master** node by using the same command, the re-allocation did work, but the node is still there, it is still the master.
So, my question is :do i have to kill the es process on the master host manully?

I checked the docs, there's no description on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the ElasticSearch on the master node and change the node name. When it starts up, it would no longer be the master. You can then make another node within the cluster the master.

Comment: Yes, or you could try making another node the master to see if this one gets decommissioned automatically as master? I didn't find any documentation on this either.